# Android VideoView: should not mute audio of other apps

Tags: android, audio

I'm creating an VideoView which infinitely loops a video playback - works fine. These videos are without sound, thus I do not need exclusive sound access or whatever. Instead, what happens is that as soon as the VideoView is initialized and the playback (of a video with no sound) starts, the sound of any other app will be muted, e.g., if in background I'm listening to some music, it will be muted. Is there any way to prevent the VideoView from muting other apps' sound output?

Here's my code (excerpt):

```
videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(mediafile));
videoview.requestFocus();
videoview.start();
```